# Why does Microsoft Edge ignore td width?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I expected all browsers behave the same, which is setting all tds in a table to the width of the largest width indication of all tds.

Take a look at the following examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/rpkbf4n6/

```
=> This one is displayed correct in FF/IE but wrong in Edge (the very long text is not wrapped)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8oa4fw2u/

```
=> This one is displayed correct in FF/IE/Edge
```

Why is this? I don't like to give all tds the width attribute and I don't like to give the width attribute to the largest content td (because the content is filled dynamically, so I don't know which is the largest)

Comment: have you tried it with [table-layout:fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) ?

Comment: Yes, does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a DIV above the table and use **table-layout: fixed** then it works with Edge

```
<div class="wrap">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100px;">
          <span>Text</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="width:160px;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>Very very very very very long text</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to give a fixed width to the whole container. My solution now is to give these tds a width of 1px. I can live with that.